# How to speed up string cleanup function?

Tags: postgresql, performance, plpgsql, replace, unaccent, postgresql-performance

I need to cleanup a string, so that certain ASCII code characters are left out of the string, and others are replaced.

I am new to Postgres. My function `ufn_cie_easy()` performs way too slow:

```
DECLARE
  letter char = '';
  str_result TEXT = '';
  x integer;
  y integer;
  asc_code int;
BEGIN
  y:=1;
  x:=char_length(arg);
  LOOP
    letter=substring(arg from y for 1);
    asc_code=ascii(letter);
    IF (asc_code BETWEEN 47 and 58) or (asc_code BETWEEN 65 and 90) or (
        asc_code BETWEEN 97 and 122) THEN
      str_result := str_result || letter;
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 192 and 197) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'A';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 200 and 203) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'E';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 204 and 207) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'I';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 210 and 214) OR (asc_code=216) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'O';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 217 and 220) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'U';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 224 and 229) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'a';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 232 and 235) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'e';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 236 and 239) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'i';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 242 and 246) OR (asc_code=248) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'o';
      ELSIF (asc_code BETWEEN 249 and 252) THEN
      str_result := str_result || 'u';
      ELSE
      CASE asc_code
        WHEN 352 THEN str_result := str_result || 'S';
        WHEN 338 THEN str_result := str_result || 'OE';
        WHEN 381 THEN str_result := str_result || 'Z';
        WHEN 353 THEN str_result := str_result || 's';
        WHEN 339 THEN str_result := str_result || 'oe';
        WHEN 382 THEN str_result := str_result || 'z';
        WHEN 162 THEN str_result := str_result || 'c';
        WHEN 198 THEN str_result := str_result || 'AE';
        WHEN 199 THEN str_result := str_result || 'C';
        WHEN 208 THEN str_result := str_result || 'D';
        WHEN 209 THEN str_result := str_result || 'N';
        WHEN 223 THEN str_result := str_result || 'ss';
        WHEN 230 THEN str_result := str_result || 'ae';
        WHEN 231 THEN str_result := str_result || 'c';
        WHEN 241 THEN str_result := str_result || 'n';
        WHEN 376 THEN str_result := str_result || 'Y';
        WHEN 221 THEN str_result := str_result || 'Y';
        WHEN 253 THEN str_result := str_result || 'y';
        WHEN 255 THEN str_result := str_result || 'y';
        ELSE str_result := str_result;
      END CASE;
      END IF;    
    y:=y+1;
    exit when  y=x+1;
  END LOOP;
  return str_result;
END;
```

Comment: Thx for your reply.

Data is imported from MS Access and into a PG db with UTF-8 character set.
A conversion from one char set to another (e.g. LATIN5 to UTF-8) will not help, because this is a user defined function in which certain characters are simply omitted from the string, and others replaced.
(The asc_code values are not a problem I'm coping with btw, they have been tested).
The function works fine for a few records, but I need to use it for multiple calculated fields on a few million records. Takes forever.

Answer (score 2):

The function should be noticeably faster with ***fewer assignments*** (none, actually, in this updated version):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_cie_easy(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
         translate($1,'ŠŽšžŸÝÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰‹‘’“”•–—˜™›¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿×Þð÷þÐ'
                     ,'SZszYYAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy')
         ,'Œ','OE')
         ,'Æ','AE')
         ,'œ','oe')
         ,'æ','ae')
         ,'ß','ss')
         ,'''','');
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Assignments are comparatively expensive in plpgsql.

But I suspect you really want to **remove *all* accents (diacritic signs)**. Postgres provides the function `unaccent()` with the additional module [**unaccent**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/unaccent.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_cie_easy(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT translate(unaccent(
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
          $1
         ,'Œ','OE')
         ,'Æ','AE')
         ,'œ','oe')
         ,'æ','ae')
         ,'ß','ss')
       ), '!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰‹‘’“”•–—˜™›¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿×Þð÷þÐ''', '');
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Substantially faster, yet. And superior in every aspect if you actually want to remove *all* diacritic signs.

In addition to `unaccent()`:

- Include an escaped `'` (`''`) in `translate()` directly.
- Make it a simple SQL function.
- Make the function `IMMUTABLE`.

Detailed explanation and more related issues to consider if you need an `IMMUTABLE` function with `unaccent()`:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

In Postgres 9.5 or older we need to expand ligatures like 'Œ' or 'ß' manually, since `unaccent()` always substitutes a *single* letter:

```
    SELECT unaccent('Œ Æ œ æ ß');

    unaccent
    ----------
    E A e a S
```

### What I would do in Postgres 9.6

After [this update to unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html#AEN130518):

> Extend `contrib/unaccent`'s standard `unaccent.rules` file to handle all
>   diacritics known to Unicode, and **expand ligatures correctly** (Thomas
>   Munro, Léonard Benedetti)

Bold emphasis mine. Using `unaccent()` like instructed in the linked answer above:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_cie_easy(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(public.unaccent('public.unaccent', $1)
                                        , '[^a-zA-Z\d\s]', '', 'g')
                         , '\s+', ' ', 'g'));
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Almost, but not quite 100 % identical to what you had. ***Better*** IMHO:

1. Replace all accents and expands all ligatures with `unaccent()`.
2. Remove all noise characters (everything except ASCII letters, digits and white space).
3. Fold whitespace to a single space (`' '`).
4. Trim leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: That's briliant help, Erwin, thx so much.

Comment: @W.Smets: It gets better, yet. Consider the updates.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you could use `translate()` to achieve what you want.

A small demonstration:

```
SELECT translate('Some ţext with ひ inţereşt平ing chăracters', 'ţşăひ平', 'tsa');
               translate                
────────────────────────────────────────
 Some text with  interesting characters
```

So, first you put the characters you want to replace, each matching (in the given order!) their replacement in the third parameter to the function.  Then just list all characters that has to be removed, with no match in the replacement list.

For those characters that need a multi-character replacement, you can still use `replace()` in a similar fashion, but one call per character:

```
SELECT replace(replace('Æ small blæblæ', 'Æ', 'AE'), 'æ', 'ae');
      replace      
───────────────────
 AE small blaeblae
```

Comment: Right! That looks very promising.
Especially if I could build up the second parameter of the replace function using code.
In VB(A) you would have a static variable calculated once.
Any suggestions as how to get PostgreSQL (using SQL Manager for PostgreSQL) to calculate a value once and reuse it as a variable in functions?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, reworked version of the function (incoming: text_to_clean text).
Doesn't look nice, but works:

```
DECLARE
result text;
BEGIN
result=translate(text_to_clean,'ŠŽšžŸÝÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰‹‘’“”•–—˜™›¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿×Þð÷þÐ','SZszYYAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy');
result=replace(result,'Œ','OE');
result=replace(result,'Æ','AE');
result=replace(result,'œ','oe');
result=replace(result,'æ','ae');
result=replace(result,'ß','ss');
result=replace(result,'''','');
return result;
END;
```

Thanks again for the help.